# PDF of training manual for QGIS 3.26

Tags: qgis

Is there a PDF of training manual for QGIS 3.26? The documentation site only goes up to 3.22 -

https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/index.html

Comment: You can base yourself on the 3.22 version and look at the new features for 3.24 & 3.26 with the Visual changelogs : https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelogs.html

Answer (score 1):

Only LTR versions have documentation.

"Documentation is versioned and translated only for QGIS Long Term Releases (LTR), meaning that if you are running a regular release (eg, QGIS 3.0), the help button will by default open the next LTR manual page (ie. 3.4 LTR), which may contain description of features in newer releases (3.2 and 3.4). If no LTR documentation is available then the testing doc, with features from newer and development versions, is used."

Source: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html

Comment: False, there is 'testing' which should be more up to date.